# Yolo high mAP but fairly low confidence

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

I am currently working on a project which makes use of YOLOv5. I have trained my model for 100 epochs on a 5000+ dataset of images and got a good mAP of 0.95. My question came up when I tried to detect objects using the detect.py with the trained weights I got fairly low confidence in detection about 0.30 to 0.70 on certain objects. Should I train my model for more epochs to better my confidence? and does high mAP not result in high confidence?